# Invalid operator error oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in my source. IT has 2 columns period(varchar) and Center(varchar). Center has the below values L150 L180 L352 and period has NULLS.

I'm trying to run this query

```
select TIP.PERIOD
  from SCOTT.TIP
 where (1=1)
       and (
         CASEWHEN TIP.CENTRO IN ('L150','L180','L358')
             THEN TIP.PERIOD = 'C'
             ELSE TIP.PERIOD = 'D'
              END)
```

But I'm getting invalid relational operator error. what could be the reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select TIP.PERIOD
from SCOTT.TIP  
where 
  TIP.PERIOD = 
    CASE
      WHEN TIP.CENTRO IN ('L150','L180','L358') THEN 'C'
      ELSE 'D'
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong

```
CASEWHEN
```

change it yo

```
CASE WHEN 



select TIP.PERIOD
   from SCOTT.TIP  where (1=1) and (
   TIP.PERIOD = CASE WHEN TIP.CENTRO IN ('L150','L180','L358')
   THEN TIP.PERIOD = 'C'
   ELSE TIP.PERIOD = 'D'
   end)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, tip.period is a null value that you're "defining" during the query?

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN TIP.CENTRO IN ('L150','L180','L358')
        THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'D'
    END as period
from scott.tip
```

Answer (score 0):

For full-on Oracle syntax you'll need something like this:

```
select TIP.PERIOD
from SCOTT.TIP
where (1=1) and (
 TIP.PERIOD =
   CASE WHEN TIP.CENTRO IN ('L150','L180','L358') THEN 'C' ELSE 'D' END
```